# Counting duplicates in a sorted sequence using command line tools

Tags: bash, command-line-interface, count

I have a command (cmd1) that greps through a log file to filter out a set of numbers. The numbers are in random order, so I use `sort -gr` to get a reverse sorted list of numbers. There may be duplicates within this sorted list. I need to find the count for each unique number in that list.

For example, if the output of cmd1 is

```
100 100 100 99 99 26 25 24 24
```

I need another command that I can pipe the above output to, so that I get :

```
100 3 99 2 26 1 25 1 24 2
```

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1092405/counting-duplicates-in-a-sorted-sequence-using-command-line-tools

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you can handle the output being in a slightly different format, you could do:

```
cmd1 | tr " " "\n" | uniq -c
```

You'd get back:

```
  3 100
  2 99
  1 26
  1 25
  2 24
```

Comment: +1 for simplicity.  You could do one final pipe to "awk '{print $2 " "$1}'" to get the columns switched.

Comment: and after doing that awk, you could do "| tr '\n' ' '" to get it all on one line

Comment: Or use printf to get it all on one line.

Answer (score 1):

Also add in the -u switch. Thus you would have:

```
cmd1 | sort -gru
```

From the sort manpage:

-u, --unique
without -c, output only the first of an equal run

Comment: But he wants the count.

Comment: specifics, specifics :)<br />
cmd1 | sort -gru | wc -l

Answer (score 0):

(I'm assuming your input is one number per line, as that's what sort would output.)

You could try awk:

`<your_command> | awk '{numbers[$1]++} END {for (number in numbers) print number " " numbers[number]}'`

This would give you an un-sorted list (the order in which arrays are walked through in awk are undefined, so far as I know), so you'd have to sort to your liking again.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ echo '100 100 100 99 99 26 25 24 24' | perl -e 'while (<>) { chomp; my %nums; foreach (split(/ /)) { $nums{$_} += 1; }; foreach (sort {$b <=> $a} keys %nums) { print "$_ $nums{$_} " }; print "\n"; }'
100 3 99 2 26 1 25 1 24 2
```

Comment: This would also work with multiple lines of input, sorting each line individually.